# Playing Encrypted Video in javafx

Tags: javafx

I am trying to play encrypted videos in javafx. My first question is can I play the video using in memory bytes. I have searched and found no means that's why I decided to store the decrypted file on the machine and then playing it. The problem that I am facing is that I am wishing to play the file in parallel with the decryption process so that user does not wait for the full decryption. Is this possible.

Answer (score 0):

No, the JavaFX 8 [Media](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/Media.html#Media%28java.lang.String%29) class does not accept a input data from memory bytes.

Future releases of JavaFX may provide such capability.